# How to find the first space in a sentence with Regular Expressions within R

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I have a data.frame which contains a column with values like this:

```
[2] wererea 187w 50HH (1)
[3] werewefrea 145y 50HH (4)
[5] weredssda 100NH (2)
```

I would like to separate this column into two columns and the separation should be done at the first space. How I do it now is with the help of the `]` like this:

```
DF <- separate(DF , "X", into = c("X","Y"), sep = "\\] ", remove = TRUE)
DF$X<- gsub("\\[", "", DF$X)
```

The way to select the last space goes like this:

```
DF <- separate(DF, "X", into = c("X","Y"), sep = " (?=[^ ]*$)", remove = TRUE)
```

I found this RegEx:

```
^([^ ]*)
```

But this will select the first space AND everthing before it. 
But how do you select only the first space?

Comment: `^(?:[^ ]*)(\s)`

Comment: Maybe you could capture the data in two capturing groups. The first by matching not a space and then a space and the second group for the rest [`^([^ ]+ )(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/lEvLB6/1)

Comment: Both solutions will also select the everthing before the first space. I only want to select the first space

Comment: keep in mind that in `R`, escaping requires _two_ slashes. eg `\\s` instead of `\s` to find whitepsace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may leverage the ICU *constrained-width* lookbehind (i.e. allowing `{n,m}` quantifiers to some extent) *assuming* that the first non-whitespace chunk is not a too large value. Say, this will work if the number of whitespace chars at the string start is up to 1000:

```
separate(DF, "X", into = c("X","Y"), sep = "(?<=^\\S{0,1000})\\s+", remove = TRUE)
```

The `(?<=^\\S{0,1000})\\s+` pattern will match 1 whitespaces that are preceded with start of string followed with 0 to 1000 non-whitespace chars.

Else, you may use [`tidyr::extract`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/extract.html):

```
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
    extract(col="X", into = c("X","Y"), regex="^(\\S+)\\s+(.*)")
```

If you want to avoid the first `[...]` around a number, use a slight variation:

```
extract(col="X", into = c("X","Y"), regex="^\\[(\\d+)]\\s+(.*)")
```

The `^(\\S+)\\s+(.*)` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(\\S+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars (it will the first column value from the `into` list) (in the other pattern, `(\\d+)` will capture 1 or more digits)
- `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Capturing group 2: any one or more chars (it will the second column value from the `into` list).

Comment: I had to change the regex to: `regex="(\\S+)(.*)")` to get it to work

Comment: @Artie16 So, that means you wanted to have the first space in the second column.

Comment: @Artie16 See an update with another `extract` function that extracts numbers from `[...]` into Column "X".

Comment: Alright there was a mistake in my real DF and because of that your solutions didn't work. I corrected the DF and now all three of your solutions work. Initially I wanted `[5] weredssda 100NH (2)` to split in `[5]` and `weredssda 100NH (2)` and after that I would remove the `[` `]`. But your solution
`DF %>%
    extract(col="X", into = c("X","Y"), regex="^\\[(\\d+)]\\s+(.*)")`
does this in one step.

Answer (score 0):

The question was not specific regarding the exact output required so it is assumed that the output should be two columns X and Y such that the first column is the numeric row number and the second column is the text after the space that separates it from the row number.  In that case the default regular expression used by `separate` should be fine if the junk is removed afterwards:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  separate(X, into = c("junk", "X", "Y"), 
    extra = "merge", convert = TRUE, remove = TRUE) %>%
  select(-junk)
```

giving:

```
  X                        Y
1 2    wererea 187w 50HH (1)
2 3 werewefrea 145y 50HH (4)
3 5      weredssda 100NH (2)
```

### Alternative

An alternative to removing junk afterwards is removing the [ before:

```
DF %>%
  mutate(X = sub(".", "", X)) %>%
  separate(X, into = c("X", "Y"), 
     extra = "merge", convert = TRUE, remove = TRUE)
##   X                        Y
## 1 2    wererea 187w 50HH (1)
## 2 3 werewefrea 145y 50HH (4)
## 3 5      weredssda 100NH (2)
```

### Note 1

Note that there is an [open issue #397](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/397) in tidyr which if implemented would reduce the above to the following code. (Update: tidyr 0.8.2 now implements this feature)

```
DF %>%
  separate(X, into = c(NA, "X", "Y"), 
    extra = "merge", convert = TRUE, remove = TRUE)
```

### Note 2

The input in reproducible form:

```
DF <-
structure(list(X = c("[2] wererea 187w 50HH (1)", "[3] werewefrea 145y 50HH (4)", 
"[5] weredssda 100NH (2)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This is indeed what I wanted to end up with. I thought to seperate into `[2]` and `[wererea 187w 50HH (1)]` and then remove the `[` `]` from the first column. This actually does it in one step. Thanks

Comment: @Artie16 You do not need to remove anything if you use `extract(col="X", into = c("X","Y"), regex="^\\[(\\d+)]\\s+(.*)")` but it is not clear what you need to get in the end, as you have not included expected result into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation. It pulls the number out of the column, then gets rid of it in the first column. An advantage here is that the number that is pulled out is of class numeric (you could always convert from character with the other methods as well).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Y = parse_number(X),
         X = gsub("\\[.*\\]", "", X))
#>                           X Y
#> 1     wererea 187w 50HH (1) 2
#> 2  werewefrea 145y 50HH (4) 3
#> 3       weredssda 100NH (2) 5
```

Created on 2018-09-20 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).